How to use libpixman-1.so instead of libpixman-1.so.0 when building qemu-system-x86_64?
I added libqemu-system-x86_64.so to my Android app and this happened:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libpixman-1.so.0" not found: needed by /data/app/~~YmgfV_r_SsPz1J1zbWewhg==/com.may.app-Oh1cEHuN2dua7bP6EpkE3w==/lib/arm64 /libqemu-systemjava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libpixman-1.so.0" not found: needed by /data/app/~~YmgfV_r_SsPz1J1zbWewhg==/com.my.app-Oh1cEHuN2dua7bP6EpkE3w==/lib/arm64 /libqemu-system-x86_64.so
I want to build qemu so that it uses libpixman-1.so directly instead of going through a shortcut.
